# i can figure out why but the likeness (lk) is more than it can should be, could anyone help me fix it?

Tags: python

the likeness (lk) is the number of the same letters in the password and userans.But the likeness is ending up bigger than the actual word.For example if the password was pie and the guess was "die" instead of the likeness being 2 because the numbers of "i" & "E" are the same it would come up with a number like 18 which is too big.

````
    import time
    import random
    gus=4
    words_file =open('words.txt','r')
    all_words = words_file.read()
    words_file.close()

    all_words = all_words.split('\n')
    password = 0

    word = random.choice(all_words)
    word2 = random.choice(all_words)
    word3 = random.choice(all_words)
    word4 = random.choice(all_words)
    word5 = random.choice(all_words)
    word6 = random.choice(all_words)
    word7 = random.choice(all_words)

    print("ADMIN OVER PASS ERROR 1231394/123\198")
    a1 = random.randint(1,7)
    if a1==1:
    password=word

if a1==2:
    password=word2

if a1==3:
    password=word3

if a1==4:
    password=word4

if a1==5:
    password=word5
if a1==6:
    password=word6
if a1==7:
    password=word7




print(word)
print(word2)
print(word3)
print(word4)
print(word5)
print(word6)
print(word7)
guss=20

while guss>0:
    print("")
    print("number of tries",guss)
    userans=input("password")
    lk=0
    if userans==password:
        guss=-1
        print("password correct")
    else:
        guss -= 1
        a=userans.count(a)
        b=userans.count(b)
        c=userans.count(c)
        d=userans.count(d)
        e=userans.count(e)
        f=userans.count(f)
        g=userans.count(g)
        h=userans.count(h)
        i=userans.count(i)
        j=userans.count(j)
        k=userans.count(k)
        l=userans.count(l)
        m=userans.count(m)
        n=userans.count(n)
        o=userans.count(o)
        p=userans.count(p)
        q=userans.count(q)
        r=userans.count(r)
        s=userans.count(s)
        t=userans.count(t)
        u=userans.count(u)
        v=userans.count(v)
        w=userans.count(w)
        x=userans.count(x)
        y=userans.count(y)
        z=userans.count(z)

        a2=password.count(a)
        b2=password.count(b)
        c2=password.count(c)
        d2=password.count(d)
        e2=password.count(e)
        f2=password.count(f)
        g2=password.count(g)
        h2=password.count(h)
        i2=password.count(i)
        j2=password.count(j)
        k2=password.count(k)
        l2=password.count(l)
        m2=password.count(m)
        n2=password.count(n)
        o2=password.count(o)
        p2=password.count(p)
        q2=password.count(q)
        r2=password.count(r)
        s2=password.count(s)
        t2=password.count(t)
        u2=password.count(u)
        v2=password.count(v)
        w2=password.count(w)
        x2=password.count(x)
        y2=password.count(y)
        z2=password.count(z)
        if a==a2:
            lk+=1
        if b==b2:
            lk+=1
        if c==c2:
            lk+=1
        if d==d2:
            lk+=1
        if e==e2:
            lk+=1
        if f==f2:
            lk+=1
        if g==g2:
            lk+=1
        if h==h2:
            lk+=1
        if i==i2:
            lk+=1
        if j==j2:
            lk+=1
        if k==k2:
            lk+=1
        if l==l2:
            lk+=1
        if m==m2:
            lk+=1
        if n==n2:
            lk+=1
        if o==o2:
            lk+=1
        if p==p2:
            lk+=1
        if q==q2:
            lk+=1
        if r==r2:
            lk+=1
        if s==s2:
            lk+=1
        if t==t2:
            lk+=1
        if u==u2:
            lk+=1
        if v==v2:
            lk+=1
        if w==w2:
            lk+=1
        if x==x2:
            lk+=1
        if y==y2:
            lk+=1
        if z==z2:
            lk+=1
        print("likeness=",lk)
    if guss==0:
        print("ADMIN FAILED")
       ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You add to the likeness for every letter *that does not appear in either word*.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few edits to the code to make it shorter and implemented Scott Hunter's solution.

```
import time
import random
gus=4
words_file =open('words.txt','r')
all_words = words_file.read()
words_file.close()

all_words = all_words.split('\n')
password = 0

# let's set up a list for the 7 words instead of 7 variables - this will make the code shorter
words = []

for i in range(7):
    words.append(random.choice(all_words))
# words will have indexes from 0 to 6


print("ADMIN OVER PASS ERROR 1231394/123\198")
a1 = random.randint(1,7)
password = words[a1-1]

for word in words:
    print(word)

guss=20

while guss>0:
    print("")
    print("number of tries",guss)
    userans=input("password")
    lk=0
    if userans==password:
        # guss=-1
        print("password correct")
        break  # this way is more straightforward: you print stuff and explicitly exit the loop
    else:
        guss -= 1
        for letter in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            if userans.count(letter) == password.count(letter): # this is for convenience
                if userans.count(letter)>0: # this is the solution to your question
                    lk += 1

        print("likeness=",lk)
    if guss==0:
        print("ADMIN FAILED")
```

Comment: I’m sorry but could you explain this in more detail because I’m fairly new to python so I want to know what I did wrong so I can learn from it and remember it for future projects.@llia Gilmjarow

Comment: You did almost everything right. The problem was in the fact that you were increasing `lk` when count of a given letter in both `userans` and `password` was the same, **even if** the count was zero, in other words you were counting also every letter that wasn't there in those words. I added a condition to only icrease `lk` when one of them is greater than zero (and because they must be equal for that condition to even be checked, the other must too be greater than zero). Other than that, I used loops where you coded variables and comparisons by hand. this way code is shorter and easier to read